# iOS - Floating Single Button

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I need a floating button in my iPhone app, I saw many libraries online like this one: https://cocoapods.org/pods/LiquidFloatingActionButton

But I need it to be just a single button, not a menu - Do you know of any other libraries that do this? Or a way to customise one of the current libraries to do what I need?

Thanks!

Comment: first create the button and then get key window and then call keywindow.addSubview(button). Define the frame of the button to the place you want it to be floated.

Comment: Aghanim Scepter +1.

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

final class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        let buttonDiameter: CGFloat = 44.0
        let floatingButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: buttonDiameter, height: buttonDiameter))
        floatingButton.layer.cornerRadius = buttonDiameter / 2.0
        floatingButton.backgroundColor = .redColor()
        window?.addSubview(floatingButton)

        return true
    }
}
```

This example would add a floating button to the top left corner of your app.

The important aspect of this code is that I am adding the button the `UIWindow`.

You can access the `window` of the app from any `UIViewController` whose view is added to the window via the property `window`.

To get notifications when a view controller is added to the `window` you can override the function:

`didMoveToWindow()`

Comment: Hey! Thanks for this, I tried it but it didn't show up, is there something wrong? @infinity-james

Comment: Please don't take the code literally.
This code won't work because the other views will be added on top of it.

Comment: Use the `window` property of the view controller like I described.

Comment: so this code is jot enough? What do I have to add in each view controller for this to work?

Comment: Don't think adding objects to window is a good idea. window is supposed to be a container for viewcontrollers.

Answer (score 0):

There is an approach to this by using KCFloating action button and adding a tapGestureRecognizer to a view containing this button.

So, just adding KCFloatingActionButton's pod and adding another view containing it it's possible to have a single floating action button just as androids.

If you require more detail to solve this issue tell me and I'll try to help

Sample image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

only copy and paste this code

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

            layoutFAB()
        }

        func layoutFAB() {
            let item = KCFloatingActionButton()
            item.buttonColor = UIColor(red: 188/255, green: 46/255, blue: 35/255, alpha: 1)
        }

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            let Fab = KCFloatingActionButton()

            Fab.addItem("a", icon: UIImage(named: "a")){ item in
               print("a")
            }
            }

            self.view.addSubview(Fab)
        }
```